# Highlighting buttons on keyboard shortcut

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I have a keyboard combination of CTRL + SHIFT + A, CTRL + SHIFT + B etc for various buttons on my WPF UI.

I have a requirement where in, when the user presses, CTRL + SHIFT, I need to highlight the appropriate letter, on the text of each button, which in turn aids the user, in easily determining which alphabet for which option.

I have almost used up all the 26 alphabets. So I cannot ask the user to memorize each option.

Is there a way I can achieve this, can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: I have lots of menus as well.. as a result, I go for CTRL + SHIFT combination as all the ALT combinations have been mostly occupied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way would be to define a Custom `Window`, e.g. `ShortCutWindow`

You will probably want to use it to define an attached property, that can be added to all controls.
e.g.

```
 <ShortCutWindow ....>
    <Button ShortCutWindow.DisplayShortCut="K"/>
    ....
 </ShortCutWindow>
```

In the window add a handler (maybe `OnPreviewKeyDown`) so that when `Ctrl-Shift` is detected, then it iterates through all the controls, finds the attached property and renders a tooltip.

Comment: that sounds nice.. but I have a small concern.. If I have some tooltip content that I wish to display like help text, that will get over written.. please correct me if I am wrong. (may be I can template that too. but still its got to be one at a time..)

Comment: That would be the case if you replace the `Button.Tooltip` but I was actually expecting that you would simply add a new Tooltip to the `Button`'s Adorner layer. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx